# How to make the line above a different colour?

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am making a slot machine and whenever you get a certain fruit (apple, cherry or banana) it changes colour to that fruits colour. I have the code working for it choosing a random fruit and it changes colour but, when it changes colour it only changes the colour of the lines below and not the actual line that it is meant to. So does anybody know how to make the line above you change colour.

```
slot1 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
    slot2 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
    slot3 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}



    RandomNumber = rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)

    Console.WriteLine(slot1(RandomNumber))
    slotmachine1 = slot1(RandomNumber)


    If slotmachine1 = "Apple" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Cherry" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Banana" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    End If
```

Comment: I imagine you need to change the colour before writing to the console instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Console.WriteLine(slot1(RandomNumber));` is the portion that needs a different color, this would be the answer.

```
// Method for performing a lever pull on the slot machine
Public Sub PullLever() {
    // Slot Fruits
    slot1 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
    slot2 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}
    slot3 = {"Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"}


    // Randomize fruit
    RandomNumber = rand.Next(0, slot1.Length)
    // Get the fruit name
    slotmachine1 = slot1(RandomNumber)

    // Choose Color
    If slotmachine1 = "Apple" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Cherry" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    ElseIf slotmachine1 = "Banana" Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    End If

    // Write to console the chosen fruit
    Console.WriteLine(slotmachine1);
}
```